# WOL on single host with multiple NICS in same subnet

Tags: networking, subnet, nic, wake-on-lan

apologies if this has been answered before but I have not been able to find this specific kind of scenario and I'm not sure how to filter search results for something like this. Here is my scenario, also forgive me I am more towards the begginer side of networking :)

I have an intel SFP+ dual port PCIE card and two server on-board NIC's all within the same host on the same subnet.
The on board NIC's support WOL while the PCIE card does not.

I only need the on-board NIC available so I can do WOL, otherwise I would like to use the PCIE link for all other communication.

The goal would be that I can send WOL requests as well as interact with the server on the same subnet as I do not have any other networks configured in my LAN currently.

I wanted to confirm if this is possible and if so how I should proceed. I have looked into NIC teaming but it seems this may be more for load balancing/fault tolerance than what I am after, if that's not the case I would be curious what the recommendation there would be as well. I would be open to more hacky solutions but would also be curious what an overall best practice/approach woud be for this kind of scenario.

Thank you!

Comment: Each NIC has a unique MAC address (Layer 2). WoL operates on Layer 2. I don't see the conundrum.

Comment: WoL has nothing to do with subnets or IP (either IPv4 or IPv6). The target interface does not even need a network address to be configured.

Comment: Thanks joeqwerty and Ron Maupin, this makes sense. So the reason I posted was that after linking the onboard NIC that supports WOL to the same network that the SFP+ NIC is linked, I was unable to ping or RDP to the SFP+ NIC. This made me think that maybe running the two NIC's in in this way to utilize WOL had caused issues.

Comment: I see from the switch UI the link keeps going on and off for the SFP+ port while the on board NIC seems steady so this is the actual issue. Am I doing something I shouldnt by running two NIC's from the same host with different IP's within the same subnet? The reason I ask is when I was not using the on board NIC in parallel, I did not see this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by joeqwerty and Ron Maupin, since the two devices have a unique MAC address there should not be any issues at the layer 2 level. Issue seems to be higher up, closing this question.